# IE does not support Array includes or String includes methods

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-2016

I have been working on a project and developing a JavaScript framework. The original code is about 700 lines so I only pasted this line. The includes method doesn't work on Internet Explorer. Is there any solution for this?

```
var row_cells = tbl_row.match(/<td[\s\S]*?<\/td>/g);

    row.Cells = new Array();
    if (onRowBindFuncText != null) { /*Fonksyon tanımlanmaışsa daha hızlı çalış*/

        var cellCount = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < row_cells.length; i++) {

            var cell = new Cell();
            $.each(this, function (k, v) {

                if ((row_cells[i]+"").includes("#Eval(" + k + ")")) {

                    cell.Keys.push(new Key(k,v));
```

...Code goes on

Comment: Is there any equivalent method ? Don't people check if a str is included in other str in internet explorer ? :)

Comment: I just solved that by using indexOf method..

Answer (score 76):

Because it's not supported in IE, it is not supported also in Opera ([see the compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility)), but you can use the suggested [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill):

> **Polyfill**
>
> This method has been added to the ECMAScript 2015 specification and may not be available in all JavaScript implementations yet. However, you can easily polyfill this method:

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
  String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof start !== 'number') {
      start = 0;
    }

    if (start + search.length > this.length) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @InferOn. This is great stuff. I'm picking up JavaScript right now, but wanted to ask what exactly the `arguments` variable being passed into `apply()` is? I `console.log()` it in IE and see that it is some sort of `Argument` object, but I don't understand where it's coming from exactly since it doesn't appear to be defined anywhere.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments could help you

Answer (score 50):

@Infer-on shown great answer, but it has a problem in a specific situation. If you use for-in loop it will return includes "includes" function you added.

Here is another pollyfill.

```
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "includes", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(obj) {
        var newArr = this.filter(function(el) {
          return el == obj;
        });
        return newArr.length > 0;
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: === instead of ==

Comment: may I suggest an improvement: `value: item => this.some(el => el === item)`

Comment: The question is about the includes() for string not array

Comment: Performance would not be good, when you find the first appearance you should stop iterating.

Answer (score 11):

You could just use .search() > -1 which behaves in the exact same way.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

```
if ((row_cells[i]+"").search("#Eval(" + k + ")") > -1) {
```

Answer (score 7):

This selected answer is for String, if you are looking for 'includes' on an array, I resolved my issue in an Angular project by adding the following to my polyfills.ts file:

```
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

Comment: What's up with `polyfills.ts`? Why do you have that file in your project?

Comment: Good question, I just realized that this question was not specific to Angular when I posted my answer so my answer could be confusing (I updated it to specify that it pertains to Angular).  polyfills.ts comes out of the box with a new angular (8/9/10...) project.

Answer (score 4):

This is a polyfill for TypeScript projects, taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes and modified to be valid TypeScript:

```
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
        value: function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

            if (this == null) {
                throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
            }

            const o = Object(this);
            // tslint:disable-next-line:no-bitwise
            const len = o.length >>> 0;

            if (len === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            // tslint:disable-next-line:no-bitwise
            const n = fromIndex | 0;
            let k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

            while (k < len) {
                if (o[k] === searchElement) {
                    return true;
                }
                k++;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (fullString.indexOf("partString") >= 0) {
//true 

} else {
//false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var includes = function(val, str) {
  return str.indexOf(val) >= 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery got a solution for that:

```
if ($.inArray(val,ar)===-1){
    console.log ("val not found in ar");
}
else{
    console.log ("val found in ar");
}
```

the  $.inArray(val,ar,[startingIndex]) function.