# Detecting user language in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web

I have some code that checks the user's language. If the user is German they get sent to "de.html" otherwise they're sent to "en.html". There is also a string that checks if the user is going to the editor, `('/?edit')`, and if so nothing happens. This code works fine, however, it doesn't work in IE. Any ideas?

```
var lang = window.navigator.language;
  var userLang = window.navigator.userLanguage;
  if (!window.location.href.includes('/?edit')) {
    if (lang == "de" || userLang == "de") {
      window.location.href = window.location.href + "de";
    } else {
      window.location.href = window.location.href + "en";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ie does not support 'includes' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221341/ie-does-not-support-includes-method)

Comment: The problem should have been easy to fix because the console would have told you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes()` is not supported in Internet Explorer (or Opera). You need to use `indexOf()` instead of `includes()`

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('/?edit') === -1)
//check if `window.location.href` do not include `/?edit`
```

Comment: Isn't Opera built on Blink these days?

Comment: @AndrewBone for older versions