# Polyfill for Array.includes checking NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan, polyfills

So first off this is not an issue I am facing. I was going through some `Javascript` blogs when I encountered the Array prototype methods of `.indexOf and .includes`. So if an array has `NaN` as a value, then probably `indexOf` is not going to be able to figure it out and I am left with using `.includes`. But my question here is, since the browser compatibility of `includes` actually excludes IE, what should be the alternative to detect the NaN check? I thought of constructing a polyfill by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221341/ie-does-not-support-includes-method)

```js
if (Array.prototype.includes) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "includes", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(obj) {
        var newArr = this.filter(function(el) {
          return el == obj;
        });
        return newArr.length > 0;
      }
  });
}

var arr = [NaN];
console.log(arr.includes(NaN));
```

But unfortunately, it is returning false as well. So what other options do I have? Or am I missing something out?

Comment: You can find index of NaN using `arr.findIndex()`

Comment: A polyfill for `includes()` can be [found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: @VLAZ That's what I thought too initially, but that's actually not the case! See https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero , `NaN` is the one exception. `If x is NaN and y is NaN, return true.`

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep, appears I'm wrong here. For some reason I thought I have even used `[NaN].includes(NaN)` in the past and gotten `false`. Anyway, the MDN implementation should be the correct one

Comment: Note that your polyfill should probably change `if (Array.prototype.includes) {` to `if (!Array.prototype.includes) {`

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes that I am clear, I just removed the negation so that the `includes` method actually executes this part of the code and not the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a polyfill for `Number.isNaN` as well, and then use it in your `filter` test - if both the `obj` and `el` pass `Number.isNaN`, then return true:

```js
Number.isNaN = Number.isNaN || function(value) {     
    return value !== value;
}

// if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "includes", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(obj) {
        var newArr = this.filter(function(el) {
          return el == obj || Number.isNaN(el) && Number.isNaN(obj);
        });
        return newArr.length > 0;
      }
  });
// }

var arr = [NaN];
console.log(arr.includes(NaN));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array#includes` uses the Same-Value-Zero algorithm, which is *not* the same as `==`.

Same-Value is provided by [`Object.is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is), and you can manually check for `-0` and `+0` to get the "-Zero" part of the check.

The linked page includes a polyfill, although since the polyfill includes a step to make `-0` and `+0` different - which you don't want in a Same-Value-Zero algorithm - you can just leave it out and simplify accordingly:

```
function SameValueZero(x, y) {
    return x === y || (x !== x && y !== y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of `NaN` using `firstIndex`. try like this.

```js
var arr = [NaN];
let index = arr.findIndex(Number.isNaN)
console.log(index >= 0);
```

Comment: If `includes` has to be polyfilled, then I doubt either `findIndex` or `Number.isNaN` would be available.

Comment: Also, `(index >= 0)?true:false` is completely redundant. `index >= 0` returns a boolean, so if the boolean returned is `true`, the ternary then returns...`true`. And if the boolean is `false`, it returns `false`.

Comment: @VLAZ ohh sry I missed it!!

Comment: Though this provides the answer, as @VLAZ mentioned, both `findIndex` and `Number.isNaN` is not supported in IE :(